# PHP variable variables (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, variables, syntax

I have a products detail page and I need to be able to call the appropriate work area from the database.  My columns are called: ils1275_work_area, ils975_work_area, etc.

All I need are a couple of words, so I am only returning a row.  Ordinarily to call the column with my SQL, I would do (in CodeIgniter):

```
function get_misc($item) 
{   
    $this->db->select($item);
    $this->db->where('lang', 'en');
    return $this->db->get('all_misc')->row();
}
```

And then in my PHP I would echo `$row->ils1275_work_area`.  Since on a single products detail page for multiple products, I need more flexibility than that, I need to do something like:

$row->{$laser}_work_area

But that doesn't work.  (I am supplying the value for $laser in my controller).  What syntax should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the syntax you want is

```
$row->${$laser.'_work_area'};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try forming the name of the variable as its own variable:

```
$workArea = "{$laser}_work_area";
$val = $row->$workArea;
```

Comment: @eykanal's answer is much more consise ;-)